# Excel formula or vlookup to pick latest date?

Tags: excel, function, date, formula, vlookup

i am using vlookup and want to have the latest date to be picked from multiple entries as listed below, please advise if any one can help in this regard.

[image: Latest Date]

Now i want to pick latest date for ALi, Mubeen and Nadeem from the corresponding column of date. e.g i can pick Ali and latest date for this one is 5-Dec-20.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

i think if your concern is only for Min value, then best method will be to do it by pivot tables.

Drag name to columns and date to values in pivot tables. Now convert the date value to Minimum. This will get the things done.

Hope the query is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,$B$2:$B$10))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the dates in a hidden column and get the min value like this:

The red cells formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13, SMALL(IF(D$2=$A$3:$A$13, ROW($B$3:$B$13)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")`

The blue cell formula: `=MIN(D3:D6)`

[image]

Comment: For more information about copying multycells like VLOOKUP you can look athttps://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MAXIFS function,

`=MAXIFS(B3:B6,A3:A6,C2)`

[image]